# How to write test class for Schedulable class

Tags: apex, unit-test, scheduled-apex

```
global class ScheduleBatch implements Schedulable {

    global void execute(SchedulableContext sc) {
      BatchArticleUpdateCase batch = new BatchArticleUpdateCase(); 
      database.executebatch(batch);
    }
    Public static void SchedulerMethod(){

    }
}
```

Comment: It's a method like any other, what specifically isn't clear ?

Comment: This is well-covered in the SFDC Apex doc

Answer (score 8):

you can try using this

```
@isTest
public class testScheduleBatch{  

    public static testmethod void first1(){
        Test.startTest();
        Datetime dt = Datetime.now().addMinutes(1);
        String CRON_EXP = '0 '+ dt.minute() + ' * ' + dt.day() + ' ' + dt.month() + ' ? ' + dt.year();
        testScheduleBatch.SchedulerMethod('Sample_Heading', CRON_EXP, new ScheduleBatch () );   
        Test.stopTest();
    }  

}
```

Answer (score 1):

first you have to define SchedulerMethod in which you have to call System.schedule(JobName, ScheduleTime, ScheduleBatchobj); you have to set JobName, schedule time. after that you can use following testClass.

```
@isTest
public class testScheduleBatch{

       public static testmethod void main(){

            ScheduleBatch.SchedulerMethod();
       } 
}
```